# I'm getting a NullPointerException error in Eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException error in Eclipse. Code as it stands right now:

Java:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import static java.lang.System. * ;

public class MadLib {
    private ArrayList<String> verbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MadLib() {}

    public MadLib(String fileName) {
        //load stuff
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            out.println("Houston we have a problem!");
        }
    }

    public void loadNouns() {
        nouns = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {
            Scanner chopper = new Scanner("nouns.dat");
            while (chopper.hasNext()) {
                nouns.add(chopper.next());
            }
            chopper.close();
            out.println(nouns);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            out.println("Will");
        }
    }

    public void loadVerbs() {
        verbs = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {
            Scanner chopper = new Scanner("verbs.dat");
            while (chopper.hasNext()) {
                verbs.add(chopper.next());
            }
            chopper.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            out.println("run");
        }
    }

    public void loadAdjectives() {
        adjectives = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {
            Scanner chopper = new Scanner("adjectives.dat");
            while (chopper.hasNext()) {
                adjectives.add(chopper.next());
            }
            chopper.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public String getRandomVerb() {
        String verb = "";
        int num = 0;
        num = (int)(Math.random() * verbs.size());
        verb = verbs.get(num);
        return verb;
    }

    public String getRandomNoun() {
        String noun = "";
        int num = 0;
        num = (int)(Math.random() * nouns.size());
        noun = nouns.get(num);
        return noun;
    }

    public String getRandomAdjective() {
        String adj = "";
        int num = 0;
        num = (int)(Math.random() * adjectives.size());
        adj = adjectives.get(num);
        return adj;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "The " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " after the " + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomNoun() + " while the " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " the " + getRandomNoun();
        return output;
    }
}
```

Eclipse is pointing to the issue occurring at the line`num = (int)(Math.random()*nouns.size());` but this seems to not make much sense to me.

I have the private `ArrayList<String>` initialized at the method `loadNouns`. I origianlly had `ArrayList<String> nouns` initialized at `getRandomNoun()`, but that threw a different error, so I was advised to move the initialization statement to the `loadNouns` method.

Runner Class:

```java
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab16d 
public static void main( String args[] ) {
     //make a new MadLib
     MadLib fun = new MadLib();
     out.println(fun);
}
```

Update:

The real issue appears to be that `ArrayList<String> nouns` never is "loaded up" with the separate strings which are supposed to be scanned in from the nouns.dat file

Update 2:

Java:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import static java.lang.System. * ;

public class MadLib {
    private ArrayList<String> verbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MadLib() {
        loadNouns();
        loadVerbs();
        loadAdjectives();
        out.println(nouns);
    }

    public MadLib(String fileName) {
        //load stuff
        loadNouns();
        loadVerbs();
        loadAdjectives();
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            out.println("Houston we have a problem!");
        }
    }

    public void loadNouns() {
        nouns = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {
            //nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
            String nou = "";
            Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new File("nouns.dat"));

            //chopper.nextLine();
            while (chopper.hasNext()) {
                nou = chopper.next();
                out.println(nou);
                nouns.add(nou);
                //chopper.nextLine();
            }
            //chopper.close();
            out.println(nouns.size());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            out.println("Will");
        }
    }

    public void loadVerbs() {
        verbs = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {
            Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new File("verbs.dat"));
            while (chopper.hasNext()) {
                verbs.add(chopper.next());
                chopper.nextLine();
            }
            chopper.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            out.println("run");
        }
    }

    public void loadAdjectives() {
        adjectives = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try {
            Scanner chopper = new Scanner(new File("adjectives.dat"));
            while (chopper.hasNext()) {
                adjectives.add(chopper.next());
                chopper.nextLine();
            }
            chopper.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public String getRandomVerb() {

        String verb = "";
        int num = 0;
        num = (int)(Math.random() * (verbs.size() - 1));
        verb = verbs.get(num);
        return verb;
    }

    public String getRandomNoun() {
        String noun = "";
        int num = 0;
        if (nouns == null) {
            loadNouns();
        }
        double rand = (Math.random());
        num = (int)(rand * (nouns.size() - 1));
        out.println(num);
        noun = nouns.get((int) num);
        out.print(noun);
        return noun;
    }

    public String getRandomAdjective() {
        String adj = "";
        int num = 0;
        num = (int)(Math.random() * (adjectives.size() - 1));
        adj = adjectives.get(num);
        return adj;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "The " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " after the " + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomNoun() + " while the " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " the " + getRandomNoun();
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely `nouns` is `null` when this line of code runs. You can verify this easily with a debugger. Since you have not posted any code which calls the methods of your `MadLibs` class, it is impossible to diagnose the problem for sure. Most likely `loadNouns()` has not been called when this line executes.

Comment: that's what it appears to be, as I ran the debugger in Eclipse and found the `ArrayList<String> nouns` is coming back as `null`. I'm just not sure why

Comment: When/where are you invoking `loadNouns()`?

Comment: Step through your program up until the problem occurs. Is `loadNouns()` ever called?

Comment: `loadNouns()` gets called when this entire class is called from a separate runner class

Comment: So your runner invokes `loadNouns()` and then invokes `getRandomNoun`? Why don't you move all of your load methods to an initialization method or to the constructor as a mechanism to ensure that your lists are initialized? otherwise, just do a null check and invoke the proper load method if the collection is still null.

Comment: @tech_geek23 your newly pasted main method just initialiezed MadLib object by the default contstructor, WITHOUT calling loadNouns().

Comment: so like: `public MadLib(){
loadNouns();}`?

Comment: It's appearing that now I have an `indexOutOfBounds` error being thrown

Comment: I now know my real cause, even when I call the `loadNouns` or another load method, the ArrayLists are never actually being given data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of MadLib, then printing the object in a println in your Runner class...

```
     //make a new MadLib
     MadLib fun = new MadLib();
     out.println(fun);
```

The out.println calls the toString() method you overrode in MadLib...

```
    String output = "The " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " after the " + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomAdjective() + getRandomNoun() + " while the " + getRandomNoun() + getRandomVerb() + " the " + getRandomNoun();
    return output;
```

Your MadLib object has 3 ArrayLists you never initialized, so they are null...

```
private ArrayList<String> verbs;
private ArrayList<String> nouns;
private ArrayList<String> adjectives
```

The easiest way to fix the `NullPointerException` is to initialize the variables....

```
private ArrayList<String> verbs = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();
```

However, what I really think you want to do is load all the nouns, verbs and adjectives when your object is constructed so your toString actually prints something useful.  I'd add this to your constructor as well...

```
public MadLib() {
  loadNouns();
  loadVerbs();
  loadAdjectives();
}
```

**Edit:**  Your getRandom methods need to check if the list is empty to avoid the IndexOutOfBounds exception as well...

```
public String getRandomVerb() {
    String verb = "";

    if (!verbs.isEmpty()) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * verbs.size() - 1);
        verb = verbs.get(num);
    }

    return verb;
}

public String getRandomNoun() {
    String noun = "";

    if (!nouns.isEmpty()) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * nouns.size() - 1);
        noun = nouns.get(num);
    }

    return noun;
}

public String getRandomAdjective() {
    String adj = "";

    if (!adjectives.isEmpty()) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * adjectives.size());
        adj = adjectives.get(num);
    }

    return adj;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I've loaded all the nouns, verbs, and adjs in my code in Eclipse, just didn't put it up on here. It's still showing the `nouns` as having a size of 0 (printed it out to check it)

Comment: I can only go off the code you listed, and in your sample the load methods are never called.  Anyway, I tried the code you listed in eclipse myself, and the answer I provided throws no exceptions.  I have no idea what content is in the dat files.

Comment: the .dat files contain a vertical list of that type of word fyi

Comment: the `IndexOutOfBounds` error is exactly what I'm getting, I'm having an issue getting the words from the .dat file to be objects in the ArrayList and I'm not sure what is causing it to not function.

Comment: You have to post all the code and the stack trace to get a good answer to your question.

Comment: added my code with modifications since I asked the question, see update2 in my OP